# Return multiple list statuses from twitter api

Tags: twitter

In order to perform less api calls I would like to combine api calls for multiple lists into one call - is this possible? For example if I had a list with id=123456789 I perform a call to 
    https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.json?list_id=123456789&count=15&page=1&include_entities=true

If I wanted to also perform a call to list with id=987654321 could I combine this into one api call? If so what would it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research it looks like this is not possible, I ended up having to use the REST API to get the members of each list and then follow each of those users using the Streaming API.